# What should be the mongoDb query to find number of occurrences?

Tags: php, mongodb

Sample records in the `collection`,

(doc 1)

```
[{
   "_id": ObjectId("567941aaf0058ed6755ab3dc"),
   "hash_count": NumberInt(7),
   "time": [
     NumberInt(1450787170),
     NumberInt(1450787292),
     NumberInt(1450787307),
     NumberInt(1450787333),
     NumberInt(1450787615) 
  ],
   "word": "batman" 
},
```

(doc 2)

```
   {
       "_id": ObjectId("567941aaf0058ed6755ab3dc"),
       "hash_count": NumberInt(7),

   "time": [
     NumberInt(1450787170),
     NumberInt(1450787292),
     NumberInt(1450787307),
     NumberInt(1450787333),
     NumberInt(1450787354),
     NumberInt(1450787526),
     NumberInt(1450787615) 
  ],
   "word": "apple" 
}]
```

Have stored using `PHP`,
I want to find the number of records in between time (`1450787307`) and (`1450787615`)

Answer:

```
apple=5
batman=3
```

What should be query for it?

I ran this command

```
{
aggregate : "hashtags",       
pipeline:

[
{$match:{"time":{$gte:NumberInt(1450787307), $lte:NumberInt(1450787615)}}},
{$unwind:"$time"},
{$match:{"time":{$gte:NumberInt(1450787307), $lte:NumberInt(1450787615)}}},
{$group:{"_id":"$word","count":{$sum:1}}}
]

}
```

which gave this result

```
Response from server:
{
   "result": [

  ],
   "ok": 1 
}
```

Comment: Can you please post what query you have tried and what issues you faced?

Comment: what version of `mongodb` are you using?

Comment: MongoDB shell version: 2.6.11 :)

I have tried various queries since yesterday night but they are either wrong or giving a TLE

Comment: Which version of `PHP` are you using? You need to modify the query to be compliant to the `PHP` version you use.

Comment: I ran the above command on "tools->command" panel inhomepage of rockmongo

Comment: I am using this version php5- 5.5.9
  php5-json        1.3.2-2build1

Comment: php5-json     1.3.2-2build1
 php5-cli     5.5.9

Comment: Have edited my answer to include a `PHP` version, but still am amazed how the query did  not work in `rock_mongo`. From its manual, it should.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98779/discussion-between-batscream-and-user3426424).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok , after trying a lot I have come with this answer and is correct
for
1450787615- lower limit
1450855155- upper limit

```
db.hashtags.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "time": {
                "$gte": 1450787615, "$lte": 1450855155  
            }
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$time" },
    {
        "$match": {
            "time": {
                "$gte": 1450787615, "$lte": 1450855155  
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$word",
            "count": {
                "$sum": 1
            }
        }
    }
])
```

answer is like

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "batman",
            "count" : 3
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "dear",
            "count" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "ghost",
            "count" : 1
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are stuck with an older version of `mongoDB`, you cannot leverage the power of the [`array aggregation operators`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-array/) introduced in `3.2`.

You would have to aggregate as below:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$match:{"time":{$gte:NumberInt(1450787307), $lte:NumberInt(1450787615)}}},
{$unwind:"$time"},
{$match:{"time":{$gte:NumberInt(1450787307), $lte:NumberInt(1450787615)}}},
{$group:{"_id":"$word","count":{$sum:1}}}
])
```

translated to `PHP`,

```
$result = $c->aggregate([
[ '$match' => [ 'time' => [ '$gte' => NumberInt(1450787307), 
                            '$lte' => NumberInt(1450787615) ] ] ],
[ '$unwind' => '$time' ],
[ '$match' => [ 'time' => [ '$gte' => NumberInt(1450787307), 
                            '$lte' => NumberInt(1450787615) ] ] ],
[ '$group' => [ '_id' => '$word', 'count' => [ '$sum' => 1 ] ] ]
]);
```

In version `3.2`, you could use the combination of [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter) and [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/size/) to acheive the same result and with less expensive operations.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$match:{"time":{$gte:NumberInt(1450787307), 
                 $lte:NumberInt(1450787615)}}},
{$project:{"_id":0,"word":1,
           "count":{$size:{$filter:
                               {"input":"$time",
                                "as":"t",
                                "cond":{$and:[
                                     {$gte:["$$t",NumberInt(1450787307)]},
                                     {$lte:["$$t",NumberInt(1450787615)]}]}
                                }
                           }
                    }
}}
])
```

Comment: You have very good knowledge in mongoDb thank you. :)

I am reading your various other answers too.Please keep contributing.

Comment: But when I ran this command, itdoes not give me any result :(

See my edited question

Comment: @user3426424 - welcome. will have a look into it. Just a minute.

Comment: I have provided the answer. :) I read your other answers too. You do good :)

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.find({time:{$gt: 1450787307, $lt: 1450787615}});
```

This will first give you a cursor of all docs that fit within your given time range. Once you have that you can iterate through the cursor and print out the name as well as some loop logic to find the number of occurences for each one. I've only lightly worked with mongodb so there may be a more efficient way to do this.

reference: 
https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.find/

Comment: You are right but It is very complex and time taking to iterate through the cursor.Since I have about 3000 of such mongo document in my collection.

Comment: I have provided the answer .Thank you